# How to save the values of jqgrid in a list array

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, asp.net-ajax

I have jqgrid implemented successfully, I have some questions regarding posting the data selected to controller

1. How can I maintain track of selected rows means how can I save the data in a list array?
2. How can I pass back to Data table to show the results again like no of rows selected and sum of row values selected etc. Please help. I am posting my jquery code as well as controller code. thanks in advance.

   View:

   ```
   onSelectRow: function (id, status)
       {
           alert('polo');
           var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(id);
           FirstName = rowData['FirstName'];
           LastName = rowData['LastName'];
           Salary = rowData['Salary'];
           Gender = rowData['Gender'];

           $.ajax({
               url: '/TodoList/notCk_Pk',
               data:{'FirstName':FirstName,'LastName':LastName,'Salary':Salary,'Gender':Gender},
           type: "post"
           })

           $('#example').dataTable({
               "bProcessing": true,
               "bServerSide": true,
               "sAjaxSource": "/TodoList/notCk_Pk",
               "sAjaxDataProp": "",                
               "columns": [
                          { "data": "FirstName" },
                          { "data": "LastName" },
                          { "data": "Salary" },
                          { "data": "Gender" },
               ]
           });
   }
   ```

   Controller code:

   ```
   public ActionResult notCk_Pk(String FirstName,String LastName,int Salary,String Gender)
       {                            
           l.Add(FirstName);

           l1.Add(LastName);

           i = Salary + i;
           l2.Add(Gender);
           string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmployeeContext"].ConnectionString;

           using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("data source=.; database=Srivatsava; integrated security=SSPI"))
           {
               connection.Open();
               SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insertinto", connection);
               com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName);
               com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName",LastName);
               com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", Salary);
               com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Gender);
               com.ExecuteNonQuery();
               connection.Close();

           }
           var todoListsResults = l.Count();
           var t1=l1.Count();
           var t3=l2.Count();
           var aaData=new{
                          todoListsResults,
                          t1,
                          i,
                          t3
                      };
           return Json(aaData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
           //Console.WriteLine(FirstName + "" + LastName + "" + Salary + "" + Gender);
           //return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert("+FirstName+");</script>");
       }
   ```

each time when I select a row it is initalizing the i variable to '0' even though I made it global.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use list array. You can get all selected row using `$("#ListGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow')`. Following code snippet may help you.

```
onSelectRow: function(id, status) {
     var currentRow = $(this).getRowData(id);
     FirstName = currentRow['FirstName'];
     LastName = currentRow['LastName'];
     Salary = currentRow['Salary'];
     Gender = currentRow['Gender'];

    $.ajax({
        url: '/TodoList/notCk_Pk',
        data:{'FirstName':FirstName,'LastName':LastName,'Salary':Salary,'Gender':Gender},
        type: "post"
    })

    var rows = $("#ListGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
    var totalRow = rows.length;
    var totalAmount = 0;
    $.each(rows, function() {
      var rowData = $("#ListGrid").getRowData(this);
      totalAmount += rowData["Salary"] * 1;
    });

    dataTable.row($('#example').find('tbody tr')).remove().draw();
    dataTable.row.add([totalRow, totalAmount]).draw();
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0h95Ltps/4/)